# A church-y riddle

Tags: riddle

I'm a pair of two words, and the kind of mistake
One singing a hymn might frequently make
One is a place; one a kind of battalion
Our Lord died on a cross, and not on a stallion

(what/who am I?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two words you are confusing are:

> **CALVARY** and **CAVALRY**, which only differ in the position of the 'L'.

*One is a place; one, a kind of battalion*
*Our Lord died on a cross, and not on a stallion*

> **[CALVARY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvary)** - or Golgotha - is a place just outside the walls of Jerusalem where Jesus is said to have been crucified.
>
>  Meanwhile, [**CAVALRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalry) are soldiers who fight mounted on horseback.

*...the kind of mistake*
*One singing a hymn might frequently make*

> This being the case, many Christian hymns which refer to the Crucifixion contain references to 'Calvary', and I can see it would be very easy indeed for a slip of the tongue to change it into 'cavalry'. 'Jesus dying on *cavalry*' really doesn't mean the same...!

Comment: Indeed correct! I wrote this riddle for a game at a fundraiser event held at a church, but I'm not surprised to find it an easy chestnut on this site :)